# Why does askubuntufeed on twitter post links to closed questions?

Tags: discussion

I assume the question is self explanatory.

I click on a link, *may be* with the intention of gaining rep, and I get, question closed by bla blah. *(if we have a user bla or blah, note that I'm not referring you explicitly.)*
**Result:** I get frustrated.

[@askubuntufeed](https://twitter.com/#!/askubuntufeed) Y U NO make sense?

Comment: I'd be glad to know whats wrong with the question so i can correct myself. If its my (bad?) humour, sorry. And I click through links from askubuntufeed often, when I am ol with a twitter tab open, so the question is important to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't. Those questions were closed after they were posted to the feed. As a result you click through to a closed question. Also, @askubuntufeed isn't run by anyone officially from the community. @AskUbuntu is.

Comment: must be a lag, then. Thanks for clearing that. :) btw, who manages @askubuntufeed?

Comment: All questions are posted at once, periodically. So caching somewhere by the feed itself b4 posting may also be the reason. Too bad I cant know the time of closing a question to verify. Not that it matters much, though.

Comment: @Mahesh No clue who manages it. I've tried contacting them, it appears to be a automated bot.

Comment: @jrg: silly you, it *is* a bot. Posts a bunch of upto 5 questions very synchronised in time most of the time, And I've a feeling it internally relies on AU rss questions feed, in which case it cant possibly ignore closed questions without additional effort, but still possible i guess.. (?) thanks for trying, though. :)

Comment: @Mahesh sorry, i meant that it was a automated bot based off the new questions RSS feed, which means that nobody can do anything.